# Insert Nested Objects into mongodb in python3 (Nested object is a class Instance)

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a nested structure like this:

```
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self, name, age, address):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.address = address

class Address(object):

    def __init__(self, street, pcode, another_obj):
        self.street = street
        self.postal_code = pcode
        self.another_obj = another_obj

class AnotherObject(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.someattr = 'some_init_value'


# Now i amm going to save data like this
another_obj = AnotherObject()
address = Address('xyz', 'xyz', another_obj)
obj = Student('abc', 32, address)
```

The object **obj** is an instance of a class. I am doing collection.insert_one(obj). Usually, I would do **obj.**dict**** to get "dict" of class instance which is compatible with pymongo but it does not convert the nested objects into dict too.
The problem here is that the "address" and "some_other_object" are also some other class instances and that causes **bson.errors.InvalidDocument** Exception while insertion.

Is there a way to convert nested class instances/documents (address & some_other_object) into dict or any other type acceptable to mongodb.

The package I am using for mongodb communication is pymongo v3.9.0.

**Error is TypeError:**

> document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON,
> bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from
> collections.MutableMapping

Comment: Show the class. Please read  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Add in some to_dict() methods to your classes:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


class Student(object):

    def __init__(self, name, age, address):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.address = address

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        record = {
            "name": self.name,
            "age": self.age,
            "address": self.address.to_dict() if self.address is not None else None
        }
        return record


class Address(object):

    def __init__(self, street, pcode, another_obj):
        self.street = street
        self.postal_code = pcode
        self.another_obj = another_obj

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        record = {
            "street": self.street,
            "postal_code": self.postal_code,
            "another_obj": self.another_obj.to_dict() if self.another_obj is not None else None
        }
        return record


class AnotherObject(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.someattr = 'some_init_value'

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        record = {
            "someattr": self.someattr
        }
        return record


# Now i amm going to save data like this
another_obj = AnotherObject()
address = Address('xyz', 'xyz', another_obj)
obj = Student('abc', 32, address)
db = MongoClient()['yourdatabase']
db.collection.insert_one(obj.to_dict())
print(db.collection.find_one({}))
```

Comment: what if "self.another_obj" in Address class is a list of objects, Am I going to need to call to_dict() upto the length of self.another_obj? Isn't it going to be inefficient as I am dealing with a significant amount of data?

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. If you have another specific issue raise a separate question.